# xemacs whitespace on different file types

Tags: emacs, whitespace, xemacs

I'm using xemacs , found the whitespace-cleanup very useful . However , I'm not able to operate it on different file types , it works fine on .c files , but when using on some other file extention it doesn't function .

Comment: I would take a peek inside `.../lisp/whitespace.el` and perhaps `.../lisp/obsolete/old-whitespace.el`.

Comment: Yeah , good tip , it seem like it function only on certin file types / modes , but I failed to add my mode , oh I hate lisp . Thanks anyhow ...

Comment: Install a simple mode , that does the job https://github.com/pcardune/emacs/blob/master/.site-lisp/nuke-trailing-whitespace.el